# Out of range exception of a dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hoping this is a simple one

I am extracting the data from a column of my dataset. As the SQL query is supplied an ID only one result will ever be returned. So I would think this result would always be at row '0' of the dataset.

If i click the first result in my datagrid........send the id '0' across to my second page which then extracts the image name from the DB it crashes. If I select the second result in the grid i.e '1' it is fine.

Here is my code:

```
     SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connstring);
        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("select pic from cds WHERE _id = '" + passedID + "'", sqlcon);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);
        // Rows set to '0' for the first result in the dataset but crashes if the first item is selected.
        object a = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["pic"];
        string test = a.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add  a check to be sure that your query has retrieved at least one row

```
if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    object a = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["pic"];
    string test = a.ToString();
}
else
{
    Response.Write("No rows for the ID = " + passedID);
}
```

Datasets don't have Rows. It's the DataTable contained in the Dataset that has the Rows property, but if your query fails (doesn't find a row with the ID requested) then the Rows collection has zero elements and you cannot access the index zero. (out of range)

Answer (score 0):

I would hazzard a guess that the problem is that you are either passing the wrong id, or that there is no data in the `cds` table for the passed id.

When you try to access `Rows[0]`, you get an error because there is no data, so there are no rows in the collection.